# Plugin carousel does not work on items loaded by append

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm trying to use a carousel thumbnails for my items, however the items are generated by another script, I'm trying to load the plugin for carousel but he can not identify the items.

My Real HTML:

```
<div class="prerecord_main">
   <div id="merch">
   </div>
</div>
```

after prepend by script:

```
<div class="prerecord_main">
   <div id="merch">
    <div class="product-container"></div>
    <div class="product-container"></div>
    <div class="product-container"></div>
    <div class="product-container"></div>
    <div class="product-container"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

My jQuery Plugin

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.prerecord_main #merch').slick({
      dots: true,
      infinite: false,
      speed: 300,
      slidesToShow: 5,
      touchMove: false,
      slidesToScroll: 1
    });
});
```

does not work because it can not read the items "product-container"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should run this code after adding the product-container elements. The product-container elements are not yet available on document ready.

```
$('.prerecord_main #merch').slick({
  dots: true,
  infinite: false,
  speed: 300,
  slidesToShow: 5,
  touchMove: false,
  slidesToScroll: 1
});
```

If you use chrome you can open the developer tools (F12). Then open the Console and copy the above code onto the command line and press enter. You should see a working carousel now.